# access s3 bucket from lambdaw when s3 has vpc restriction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a s3 bucket with vpc access restriction conditions

```
"Statement": [
     {
         "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only-xxxx",
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx",
             "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx/*"
         ],
         "Condition": {
             "NotIpAddress": {
                 "aws:SourceIp": "xxxx"
             },
             "StringNotEquals": {
                 "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-xxxx"
             }
         }
     }
]
```

Now I create a lambda function with a full s3 access role, and I find that the function (with simple boto3 get_object or download_file things like that) is access denied by s3. What should I add to the s3 policy to allow the function access?

The error message is

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation:
Access Denied: ClientError
 Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/var/task/SampleFunctionTest.py", line 17, in handler\n
  for obj in my_bucket.objects.all():
 ...
  botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied)
when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue. you have to create S3 Geteway Endpoint in the VPC. Goto AWS Console

[image]

Then select AWS services
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it in an option for you to put the Lambda function inside the same VPC? If so I'd go with that. Also you'd need to remove the NotIpAddress condition or add the CIDR block of the subnet your Lambda function is in.

```
"NotIpAddress": {
    "aws:SourceIp": ["xxxx", "x-lambda-subnet-ip-range"]
}
```

Comment: @Chun-KitChung you also haven't mentioned whether the Lambda Function has an EIP within the VPC. By default, Lambda's aren't connected to a VPC. If it is connected to a VPC, then the above will work. Also just to clarify, a DENY will always override an ALLOW. So your ALLOW will not override an explicit deny.